# cannot set the default selection in semantic UI selection dropdown

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have a selection dropdown where I am trying to have a default value already selected and this is turning out to be quite difficult. So, my dropdown definition is as follows:

```
<form class="ui form" method="post">
   <div class="ui fluid selection dropdown">
       <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en">
       <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
           <div class="menu">
                <div class="item" data-value="en" selected="selected"><i class="gb flag"></i>English</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="de"><i class="de flag"></i> German</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="fr"><i class="fr flag"></i> French</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="es"><i class="es flag"></i> Spanish</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="it"><i class="it flag"></i> Italian</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="pt"><i class="pt flag"></i> Portugese</div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Now, I have set the `selected` property and also set the value on the hidden input type.

Additionally, I also added this to the JS.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.ui.fluid.selection.dropdown').dropdown();
         $('.ui.fluid.selection.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', "en");
        });
</script>
```

However, none of these yield the dropdown being rendered with the default value selected.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. The only difference with your code is that I added 'search' in the class list.

```
<div id="your_elmnt_id" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown"> 
<input type="hidden" name="your_elmnt_id">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text"> comune </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="1"> item 1 </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="2"> item 2 </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="3"> item 3 </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="4"> item 4 </div>
        <div class="item" data-value="5"> item 5 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

$("#your_elmnt_id").dropdown('set selected', selected_item);